# Parse specific data using JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, xml, typescript, discord.js

Trying to find the "age" based on the "name" of the below XML data.

```
    <data>
        <user>
            <name>Joe</name>
            <age>34</age>
        </user>
        <user>
            <name>Jimmy</name>
            <age>26</age>
        </user>
    </data>
```

I used xml2json to parse this, returning

```
{"data":{"user":[{"name":"Joe","age":"34"},{"name":"Jimmy","age":"26"}]}}
```

With this, how would I be able to get the value 34 by entering in "Joe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) the string, then [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the record

```
const json = JSON.parse("...");
const joe = json.data.user.find(x => x.name === "Joe");
console.log(joe.age);
```

Comment: it would be good to have `if(joe) {} else {}` to check if `Joe` is found